# other regex patterns

Tags: java, regex

Is there exist regex pattern that includes (part1|part2|...) and [part] that do:

(part1|part2) will match either part 1, or part 2, e.g. leav(e|ing) matches leave and leaving

[part] is an optional word, e.g. cat[s] will match cat and cats

I also want to soild words that must be in every pattern e.g. give cat[s] will match give cat and give cats

Comment: I don't understand your question.  Can show us sample input and output along with how regex applies to it?

Comment: To specify optional bits in regex, you can use `?`. E.g. cats? will match "cat" and "cats", (part1)?part2 will match "part1part2" and "part2"

Comment: `leav(e|ing)(?>\\scats?)?` Would match the spec - such as it is.

Answer (score 0):

`\bcats?\b` will match both `cat`, `cats` but will not match `cat` in `cater`

`\bleav(?:e|ing)\b` will match both `leave` and `leaving`

`\bpart(?:1|2|3)?\b` will match `part1`,`part2`,`part3` or `part` but not `part` in `apart` or `partner`

**Explanation**

```
\b     // Forces a word boundary so that it does not match in the middle of a word like part in apart
(?:    //Non capturing group so that we do not have extra groups in the matches, using this is a matter of choice
|      //OR
?      //Previous char in cats previous group in (?:1|2|3) is optional
```

Note that you need to escape the `\` in `\b` while initializing the regex string.